# Error code 500 on a 404 not found page when deploying on Vercel

Tags: deployment, next.js, vercel

I deployed my app on Vercel a few months ago, all the nav links were working fine. Past month I had made some changes in the code and now my dashboard link is not working (on deployment only, works fine locally). Moreover the error it throws is a 500 on that 404 page. I've tried redeploying with build cache cleared, but nothing changed and it still doesn't work.

Code of page in question:

```js
const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json())

export default function dashboard(props) {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const userData = props.userData
    const { t } = useTranslation('dashboard')
    const router = useRouter()
    
    if (userData == undefined || !userData) {
        return <p>No data</p>
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <main className={classes.main}></main>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
        props: {
            isCreateEvent: context.query.isCreateEvent,
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(context.locale, ['dashboard'])),
   
        },
    }
}
```

And the navlink code is :

```js
<CustomButton
    href={{
        pathname: '/control',
        query: {
            isCreateEvent: false,
        },
    }}
    styleClass={classes.actionbuttons}
    typoClass={classes.headerText}
    userID={userData._id}
    id='2'
>
    <div onClick={() => handleBgChange(2)}>
        {i18nData[locale].dashboard}
    </div>
</CustomButton>
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue locally when building the app for production with `next start && next build`?

Comment: The problems is it builds fine locally, the error occurs when i deploy it on vercel.
I tried using getStaticProps and it apparently works but require query parameters for my case so i need serversiderendering in my application

Comment: Apparently removing i18Next solves the problem too, but i want this to work as I've invested great amount of time in translating through i18n